# Pandas: make new column and return list of values from other column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two columns

```
d = {'a_lower': [1, 2], 'a_upper': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

   a_lower  a_upper
0        1        3
1        2        4
```

I want to have 3rd column that returns a list from the values of the two columns

```
   a_lower  a_upper            a
0        1        3        [1, 3]
1        2        4        [2, 4]
```

I tried this

```
df['a'] = [df['a_lower'], df['a_upper']]
```

I got different result

```
    a_lower a_upper a
0   1   3   0 1 1 2 Name: a_lower, dtype: int64
1   2   4   0 3 1 4 Name: a_upper, dtype: int64
```

How to do if correcty? I am trying to return an array of dict oriented in 'records'

```
[{'a_lower': 1,
  'a_upper': 3,
  'a': [1, 3]
 },
...
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) with [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
df['a'] = df.to_numpy().tolist()
```

or to limit to specific columns:

```
df['a'] = df[['a_lower', 'a_upper']].to_numpy().tolist()
```

Alternative, using a dictionary with [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df['a'] = df[['a_lower', 'a_upper']].to_dict('list').values()
```

Output:

```
   a_lower  a_upper       a
0        1        3  [1, 3]
1        2        4  [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension:

```
df['a'] = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(df['a_lower'], df['a_upper'])]

print (df)
   a_lower  a_upper       a
0        1        3  [1, 3]
1        2        4  [2, 4]
```

Or select only both columns and convert to numpy array by [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) and then to lists:

```
df['a'] = df[['a_lower','a_upper']].to_numpy().tolist()
#if only 2 columns DataFrame
#df['a'] = df.to_numpy().tolist()
print (df)
 
    a_lower  a_upper       a
0        1        3  [1, 3]
1        2        4  [2, 4]
```

Or use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `split` parameter and select `data` key:

```
df['a'] = df[['a_lower','a_upper']].to_dict('split')['data']

print (df)
 
    a_lower  a_upper       a
0        1        3  [1, 3]
1        2        4  [2, 4]
```

---

```
print (df[['a_lower','a_upper']].to_dict('split'))
{'index': [0, 1], 'columns': ['a_lower', 'a_upper'], 'data': [[1, 3], [2, 4]]}
```